# Getting Databound Item from RecyclerView onClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have a RecyclerView with a databound item declared in the layout for the Adapter:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com...myType"/>
    <variable
        name="handlers"
        type="com...myHandlers"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="@{item.field}" />
    <Button
        android:onClick="@{handlers::onClick}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything seems to be set up properly to call the onClick handler, but the problem is, the only signature it seems to accept is

```
public class MyHandlers
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Which does precisely diddly for me, because the View that it gives me is the `AppCompatButton` that I clicked to get the `onClick`, which has no information about the databound item. I've tried checking the parents for a couple levels, but I don't see anything that will give me the databound item.

How do I get the databound item from my `onClick` so I know what item was clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **method reference**. When you use method references, parameter of the targeted method should match the parameters of the listeners you use. In this case, for onClick method, the parameter is a View, so your method has to have a View as parameter.
If you want to pass something else to the callback, then you should use **listener bindings**.  There is a discussion about that in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)
A detailed example is given above, I'm not gonna repeat that, but I want to add something. If you don't need the view argument, you don't have to pass it. You can declare it like:

```
android:onClick="@{() ->  handlers.onClick(item)}"
```

Of course, you should change the parameter type of your onClick method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener interface like:

1)
Create the following interface:

```
public interface ItemOnClickListener {
     void onClickItem(View v, myType item);
}
```

2) Change your item layout xml file like this:

```
<layout>
<data>
<variable 
    name="listener"
    type="YOUR_PACKAGE_GOES_HERE.ItemOnClickListener" />
</data>

  <Button
       android:onClick="@{(v) -> listener.onClickItem(v, item)}" />

</layout>
```

3) Implement the interface above in your adapter:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter implements ItemOnClickListener
```

4) Override the ItemOnClickListener method in your adapter

```
@Override
public void onClickItem(View v, myType item) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

5) Finally, in your `onBindViewHolder()`, give the listener instance to databinding:

```
itemBinding.setListener(this);
```